# JPQL make a query between time interval

Tags: sql, jpql

I need to make a jpql query that in sql is like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicle_db.vehicles 
WHERE vehicle_db.vehicles.TimeStampAuto BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

So i want to know how can translate the now() function and the correct syntax to select the rows 5 minutes old to now in JPQL. Thansk for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select v from Vehicules v where v.timeStampAuto between :startTime and :endTime
```

You can then compute the `startTime` and `endTime` in java (e.g. using the `Calendar` class) and pass the values to the JPQL query using the `setParamter()` method.